# Is it possible to install Google Chrome browser in CentOS 6.4

Tags: google-chrome, centos, installation

I use CentOS 6.4 and I want use google services effectively but they all require Google Chrome for better performance and I am not being able to install Google Chrome

Any Idea?

**Note:** Chromium installs successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's possible. With [this script](http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/).

Answer (score 2):

Add the url to YUM conf:

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Append Content:

```
  [chromium-el6]
    name=CentOS-$releasever - Chromium EL6
    baseurl=http://people.centos.org/hughesjr/chromium/6/$basearch/
    gpgcheck=1
    enabled=1
    gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-6
```

Then run command:

```
yum install chromium
```